# how to run a javascript function on the given date time

Tags: javascript, php, datetime

I want to run some specific `javascript function` on the given date/time only once. 
For example I have a date time variable in `php` as below.

```
  $date = "May 7, 2015 17:08:43";
```

I have some function like

```
 function some_function()
 {
   .....
   .....
 }
```

How can I run this function only once on the given date time `May 7, 2015 17:08:43`.

I tried this but it's not working correctly.

```
var date = "<?php echo date('n/j/Y/H:i', strtotime($date));?>";
var myDate = new Date();
var current_date =  (myDate.getMonth()+1)  + "/" + myDate.getDate() + "/" + myDate.getFullYear()+ "/"+ myDate.getHours() + ":" + myDate.getMinutes();
var interval = setInterval(function() { 
    if(date==current_date)
    {
       some_function();           

    }

}, 4000);
clearInterval(interval);
```

Is there any good technique for this?

Comment: i need to know what `some_function()` will do

Comment: every 4000 can skip over the minute you want....

Comment: here `some_function` is used to reload the page using `location.reload();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you can do as following:

```
setInterval(function() {
    var myDate = new Date();
    $date = "May 06 2015 13:50:40";
    var reg = new RegExp('\(' + $date.replace(/\s/g, "\\s") + '\)', 'g');
    console.log(myDate)
    if ( myDate.toString().match($date) ) {
        do_something();
    }
}, 1000);
```

here the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pj1248xq/

**Note**: You need to change the date according to real date you want to execute your `function`

Comment: This is buggy.

Despite the fact that compare timestamps by its string representation is a really bad idea, you are checking for a exact match that may never occour while your code is executed.

Javascript is single threaded and when any event (like timeout) triggers, it's handler is enqueued in the program loop to be executed as soon as possible. So when timeout fires, if you are executing a task that delays more than one second, your cumparsion will not match.

Comment: Example: function now(){return (new Date()).getTime()};<<you_function_here>>var t=now()+300000;while(now() < t){}; // If your myDate happen in about next five minutes your alert() will never be fired.

Comment: I tested it and it matches! :)

Comment: Before I posted this anwser, I made a test! :)

Comment: Sure!! It can match.

What I said is that it is not guaranteed.

If you test again in the snipped I provided above (replacing "<<your_function_here>>" with your code) you could confirm that it doesn't fire any time (even past five minutes loop).

Comment: But, it `setInterval` should be `1e3`.

Answer (score 1):

Compute the number of seconds on server side 
use `setTimeout(function(){ some_function(); }, nbreOfSeconds);`

`setInterval()` will valuates your expression at specified intervals

Answer (score 1):

You can use this javascript method. convert your given time as milliseconds.

```
setInterval(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use **setTimeout** function instead of **setInterval** as @Halayem said 
because **setTimeout** will be **executed once** **after** the **interval** **is over**

where **setInterval** will be **executed** and then wait **period**(nbreOfSeconds)  then loop again

okay you can make a ajax call using Jquery(the easy option ) and in your server side language check for the date 
and then return a json status object for example

here is a simple example :

check_date.php content(this file is used to check for the date):

```
<?php
   $date = date('n/j/Y/H:i', strtotime($date));
   if($date == 'your wanted date'){
      return json_encode(array('status'=>1));
   }else{
      return json_encode(array('status'=>0));
   }
?>
```

and this is your JavaScript code :
of course you should load jquery first

```
//here is a jquery cdn link : 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script> 
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.('check_date.php',{},function(serverRespond){
       jsonRespond = JSON.parse(serverRespond);
       if(jsonRespond.status === 1){
          setTimeout(function(){
            // here is your js function that you want to execute 
          },afterMilSeconds);

       }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function runAt (cbk, timestamp) {
    if (
        ! (timestamp instanceof Date)
        || isNaN (timestamp.getTime())
    ) throw "timestamp should be a valid Date object";
    var ms = timestamp - (new Date()).getTime();
    if (ms < 0) throw "Too late!!";
    setTimeout(cbk, ms);
};
```

You can test it "any time" with:

```
runAt(function(){console.log("Hello!!");}, new Date(new Date().getTime() + 5000));
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a small library that's useful for this over at [github](https://github.com/dirkbonhomme/infinite-timeout)

> Native setTimeout functions are limited to INT32 (2147483647 milliseconds or roughly 24.8 days). This library makes it possible to set timeouts with a nearly unlimited delay.

Once you've included the library, you can set the timeout like so:

```
// extra zeros need to get the time in milliseconds (as in JavaScript)
var date = <?php echo strtotime($date);?>000;
var id = timeout.set(some_function, date);

function some_function()
{
    // do some cool stuff
    timeout.clear(id);
}
```